# How to lock function for one user?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a Spring application that allows multiple user accounts to "vote" on a document in mongodb. This increments or decrements a field value. The user should only be allowed to upvote or downvote once (upvoting/downvoting twice should bring the value back to it's original state). However, sometimes the field value is incremented/decremented more than once by the same user. I want to implement a "lock" so that this doesn't happen. I have looked at Java Locks but I'm unsure if using this will only lock the function for a specific user, or for every user.

Comment: A lock is used for solving completely different problems - prevent concurrent access to a given resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to define a hasVoted field in your model. So...:

```
public class User {
    private boolean hasVoted = false;
}
```

When ever a user votes, check that hasVoted is false. If false, register the vote and then update hasVoted to true. If hasVoted is true, ignore the vote.

You don't necessarily need a Java feature to implement it, just adjust your logic a bit.

Comment: Interesting, but how do you know their existing logic so you recommending they change it?

Comment: I had thought about this way, but I thought there might be something more elegant

Comment: How would this be supposed to work if there was more than one document? A more reasonable way to implement the same idea would be to store a set of users who already voted in each document's data.

Comment: @kryger I have got a set of users who've already voted on each document's data. But if a user presses the upvote button quickly enough, it won't have saved the users vote before it calls the function again. The second time, it will see that the vote is still null and increment the vote count again. This solution seems to work.. Just waiting to see if anyone has anything better before I accept it.